# X-editible jquery plugin not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement The x-editible library by following the docs at http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html. i have loaded my codeigniter view with the following table filled with info from a single database table record:

```
<table id="myDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="clear: both">
<tbody>
<tr><td>id</td><td><a href="#" id="id" data-type="text" data-pk="2" data-url="/post" data-title="id">2</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>email</td><td><a href="#" id="email" data-type="text" data-pk="2" data-url="/post" data-title="email">A@B.COM</a></td></tr>
.....
.....

  <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.4.5/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#myDataTable').editable();
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
});

</script>
```

However when I click on the link in the table,like in http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html the plugin does not fire. I see no errors in firebug. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `$('#myDataTable a').editable();`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. do you want to enter it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the plugin to your links, not the table, use:

```
$('#myDataTable a').editable();
```